# Using window.document.write() in Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm using vue.js for frontend-building, but finally the my project should be able to get work in a webbrowser and in Electron.
Now i want to implement a page printing function, but it only works for the webbrowser version. I use the electron plugin for vue cli3. I can start the Electron build and also the dev mode. If I try to print data the new window gets open, but I receive `TestPrint.vue?357b:230 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at VueComponent.printCSV (TestPrint.vue?357b:230)
    at VueComponent.csvJSON (TestPrint.vue?357b:202)
    at FileReader.reader.onload (TestPrint.vue?357b:248)`

I open a new window and wanna to write html+css in the window.

```js
           var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title>');
            var css = this.getCSS()
            mywindow.document.write('<style>' + css + '</style>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');

            var printData = generatePrintData() //generate a html table
            mywindow.document.write(printData);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
```

This snippet will execute in a vue component.

Comment: [don't use](https://pomax.github.io/1473270609919) [document.write](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write). If you need things added into your document, manipulate the DOM using the normal DOM functions. Don't use a legacy low level byte pipe function that resets your document if you call it slightly too late, by design. If you have access to the document, use `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc.

Comment: I also get the errors using createElement and appendChild. ( TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined )

It's possible in Electron to open a new window via JS, but it can't read / get the html content. Maybe, the error is caused by using these functions in a vue component and not in Electron itself?

I wann create this new to generate an preview-print-page. In browser still working.

Comment: It sounds more like `window.document` simply doesn't exist, probably due to security lockdown. A quick google shows that if you want to open a new window in Electron, you don't use `window.open`, you use `new BrowserWindow`.